# Do UML diagram's typically give all member variables?

Tags: java, class-diagram

Simple question for a simple-minded person such as myself. I am quite new to programming and I have commenced working with UML diagrams for my class. Question: Are the member variables provided the in the UML diagram fixed? Am I warranted to add my own variables, or must I strictly adhere to the UML that is given for any assignment regardless of whether or not it is stated?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the purpose the diagram is supposed to serve. Usually UML class diagrams, as other types of diagrams, are created in order to communicate certain aspects of a software to other people. Then class diagrams just contain the elements (classes, member variables, methods, ...) that are required for the target audience to be able to understand these aspects.

For example, let's assume there is some kind of third-party software library you want to use. In this case you probably want to know how the interface offered by the library looks like, so you can make use of it in your own application. You are only interested in information regarding the library interface though, you do not care about its inner structure. Therefore, a class diagram that just shows all classes, methods, ..., that are visible from the outside would be sufficient for this use case and nobody would expect you to just use the depicted library classes in your implementation.

However, there are some other scenarios in which the goal of a diagram might be different. For example in the area of automated code generation, a given UML class diagram would be expected to contain all classes, methods etc. that are suppsoed to be transformed to code. Here it does not make sense to omit information, because the corresponding code snippets would not appear in the generated code subsequently.

As you can see, there is not only one single use case for UML diagrams and thus their interpretation always depends on the given context.

I hope this helps!